# Cannot Read Property 'ErrorCode' Of Undefined in Lightning Component on Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-community, ui

I am building a lightning component that needs to allow a series of fields on Case to updated by a community user. This component loads up just fine in Lightning Experience, and even in the Community Builder preview. But when I login to the community as an actual user I see this error:
**

> Cannot Read Property 'ErrorCode' Of Undefined

**
I realize this is likely a record permission or a field accessibility issue, but I have checked and the community profile has visibility and edit permissions to the field. As well as Read/Create/Update on the Case object. Interestingly however, if I load up the case detail standard page layout in community the field is editable. So this seems to be isolated to the lightning:recordEditForm component. Any ideas how to solve for this?

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" >
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Case" onerror="{!c.getError}" onload="{!c.onLoad}">
    <lightning:messages />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Description" />

    <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

```
getError : function(component, event, helper){
        debugger;
        var errorObj = event.getParams();
        var errorString = JSON.stringify(errorObj);
        console.log("@@@@:   " + errorString);
    }
```

EDIT***
Some additional information, looks like ErrorCode is a paramater returned by the onerror event object. Strinigfy spits out the whole error:

> {"message":"Cannot read property 'errorCode' of
>   undefined","detail":"","output":{},"error":{"type":"TRANSPORT_ERROR","details":{}}}

Answer (score 1):

Trace where your `errorCode` is located. What the message really means is that the project you are working on cannot find any element, property, or object named `errorCode`.

This usually happens when you are having typographical errors on variable, method or object name which you are calling.

*I will give you an example:*

I have an aura attribute `<aura:attribute name="errorCode" type="String"/>`
and I am assigning values to this attribute inside my controller by `component.set('v.errorCodes', 'This is an Error');` Notice that the attribute name and the component.set assignment names are different. It will throw you an error

> Cannot read property 'errorCodes' of undefined"

Its because you dont have any attribute named **errorCodes** in your component.

There is usually a trace code for this, have you tried tracing the source of the error by opening the `Inspector` in your browser?

Comment: I have, the error seems to be generic and produced by some backend onload functions used by the <lightning:recordEditForm> base component. I tried to supply the component with an aura:attribute with the name of the property "ErrorCode", but that didnt seem to help.

Comment: Have you checked your controller **onLoad**, since you are getting the error upon user login